# Showing that the ideal of compact operators is not necessarily closed in the weak operator topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

For any Hilbert space $H$, one can show that the ideal of compact operators, is closed with respect to the strong operator topology by using that the unit ball is weakly compact or directly in the case when $H$ is separable using a diagonal argument.

The cantor diagonal argument fails when trying to see if the ideal of compact operators, is closed in $B(H)$ with respect to the weak topology.  For this reason I have tried to find a counter example showing that $B(H)_{\text{compact}}$ is not closed in $B(H)$.

In the case when $H=:L_2(\mathbb{T})$, we have the sequence $T_n$ of elements in $B(H)_{\text{compact}})$ given by $T_n(f)=\mathscr{F}^{-1} \widehat{f(*+n)}$, i.e. the shift in fourier space.  $T_n$,a sequence of compact operators, converges in the weak operator topology to $0$ by testing against all trigonometric polynomials.

The only problem with this example is that it is not a nonexample!:  The zero map is a compact operator.

I am convinced however, that one can use an idea like this to show that the space of compact operators in $B(H)$ is not closed.

> Question: How do I do it?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "compact operators defined with respect to the strong operator topology". The "compact" is a compact operator is about the topology of $H$, not of $B(H)$.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.  I edited the question.

Comment: I'm already lost at your first sentence, since the sot closure of $K (H) $ is $B (H) $.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending your time here to help me.  I must have some misconception.  I thought that $\overline{K(H)}=K(H)$, in any topology that is at least as strong as the SOT.  Is this wrong? I'll put my proof in the next comment.

Comment: Consider matrix units with respect to an orthonormal basis, and form $P_n-\sum_{k=1}^n E_{nn}$. Then $P_n\to I$ sot (now I see that Prahlad has already put this same example in his answer). And, more generally (like I said) the sot closure of $K(H)$ is $B(H)$; it follows very easily from von Neumann's Double Commutant Theorem. And, by the way, sot closure agrees with wot closure on convex sets (so, in particular, in subspaces/subalgebras).

Answer (score 2):

The space $\mathcal{K}(H)$ of compact operators is not closed with respect to the strong operator topology (SOT) of $H$ is infinite dimensional. Take $H = \ell^2$, and let $\{e_n\}$ be the standard orthonormal basis of $H$. Then, for any $x\in H$, we may write
$$
x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
So if $P_n(x)$ denotes the $n^{th}$ partial sum of this series, then each such $P_n$ is bounded and has finite rank, and is thus compact. Also, $P_n(x) \to x$ for each $x\in H$, so $P_n \to I$ strongly, and $I\notin \mathcal{K}(H)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to see that the commutant of $K(H)$ is $\mathbb C I$. Then, using [von Neumann's Double Commutant Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem),  we have
$$
\overline{K(H)}^{\rm sot}=K(H)''=(\mathbb C I)'=B(H). 
$$

Comment: is the double commutant theorem true for subalgebras without identity?

Comment: Yes. You don't need an identity, all you need is non-degeneracy.

Comment: can you please tell me what is “non degeneracy”?

Comment: I’m following Kadison Ringrose vol 1, there I haven’t met “non degeneracy” yet!

Comment: They strongly focus on von Neumann algebras, so non-unital stuff doesn't really show on their book. An algebra $M\subset B(H)$ is *non-degenerate* if $\overline{MH}=H$. If you look at the only place in the proof of the Double Commutant Theorem where "unital" is used, you will see that it can be easily replaced by the more general condition of non-degeneracy.

Comment: Thank you @Martin Argerami

Comment: In that book they used "unital" at the end of 2nd paragraph to claim: $\tilde{x}\in [\mathfrak{\tilde{A}}\tilde{x}]$...to prove this from "non degeneracy" enough to prove that for an $x\in H$, $x\in [\mathfrak{A} x]$. Now since $x\in H=[\mathfrak{A}H]$ there exists $S_ny_n\in \mathfrak{A}H$ s.t. $||S_ny_n-x||$ is small...But we need a sequence of the form ${S_nx}$...!

Comment: but $||S_nx-x||\le ||S_nx-S_ny_n||+||S_ny_n-x||$ but here $||S_nx-S_ny||$ not necessarily small..

Comment: You are right, you don't think that way will work. I know two other ways to prove this: one is to show that if $S$ is selfadjoint then $S''=(S\cup\{I\})''$ and $\overline{S}^{\rm sot}=\overline{(S\cup\{I\})}^{\rm sot}$. The problem is that this requires proving that $\overline {SH}=H$ implies $I\in \overline{S}^{\rm sot}$, which itself requires Kaplansky's density theorem. A more direct approach can be found in Davidson's *C$^*$-Algebras by Example*, Theorem I.7.1.

Comment: Okay I checked Th I.7.1 you mentioned. There the author proved that theorem under the hypothesis "$\mathfrak{A}$ has trivial null space"...!! (I am assuming null space of $\mathfrak{A}:=\cap_{T\in \mathfrak{A}}ker(T)$

Comment: Does "non-degeneracy of $\mathfrak{A}$" $\implies$ "$\mathfrak{A}$ has trivial null space"? Here I'm assuming $\mathfrak{A}$ to be any subset of $B(H)$.

Comment: Yes, it's the same, since $\ker\mathfrak A=(\mathfrak AH)^\perp$.

Comment: Okay... Because for an $T\in \mathfrak{A}; ker(T)=[TH]^{\perp}$. This implies $ker \mathfrak{A}=\cap_{T\in \mathfrak{A}}[TH]^{\perp}=(\cup[TH])^{\perp}=(\mathfrak{A}H)^{\perp}$...Is this right??

Comment: For me, it's easier to think that if $x\in\ker\mathfrak A$, $y\in H$, $A\in\mathfrak A$, then $$\langle x,Ay\rangle=\langle A^*x,y\rangle=0,$$ so $x\in(\mathfrak AH)^\perp$. And if you start with $x\in(\mathfrak AH)^\perp$, the equality shows that $x\in\ker\mathfrak A$.

Comment: Yes…. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take the limit of projector matrices with respect to the basis $e^{2\pi in}$ that act as the identity on the first basis elements and 0 on everything else.  Then $T_n \rightharpoondown Id$ weakly.  The identity matrix is not compact because the unit ball is not compact.